# Install futures for Python 2.7 (pip install futures)

Tags: python

I'm having some problems related to MagicMirror and OpenCV ("No module named builtins"). I think it is because I haven't been able to install futures in the correct version of Python.

When I run `pip install futures` in the terminal I get a message saying Requirement already satisfied and that the futures package is in Python 3.5.

Does anyone know how I can install futures to Python 2.7? Is there a command I can use in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip2` is the package manager for Python 2 and installs packages in the Python 2 site-package directory. Run `pip2 -V` to check which version it operates on - likely that will be 2.7.